# Returning data from Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to perform operations with data coming from Firestore. I'm subscribing to an observable using valuechanges() and trying to extract an array of objects so I can create a form based on it.

It's my second time using rxjs and I've tried everything I know but couldn't make it happen. I can console.log my desired array inside the subscription but can't return it so I can use it outside.

this is the ts

```
export class ExerciseTestsComponent implements OnInit {
  exercises: Observable<any>
  exerciseForm: FormGroup;
  isAnswered: boolean; 
  isCorrect: boolean; 
  helloThere: []


  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let exerciseTest; 
    this.db
    .collection('availableExercises')
    // .doc("xvXCAxUrj4842ItZCyrv")
    // .collection("questions")
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);   
      }
      )
    console.log("below is exerciseTest ")
    console.log(exerciseTest)
    this.createGroup()
  }

  createGroup() {
    console.log("below is my firestore data")
    console.log(this.exercises)
    this.exerciseForm = this.fb.group({});
    this.exercises[0]
    .doc("xvXCAxUrj4842ItZCyrv")
    .collection("questions")
    .forEach(control =>
      this.exerciseForm.addControl(control.prefix, this.fb.control(""))
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can not return from a concurrent operation! You either have a callback or set a global variable that you set from inside the subscribe.  Read more about async nature here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit confusing as to the problem.  I think you're confusing asynchronous nature.

In you're ngonInit() you are calling `createGroup` as part of the regular method, not as part of the result handler.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let exerciseTest; 
    this.db
    .collection('availableExercises')
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);   
        // saving the response to a component local variable
        this.exercises = res;
        // I am calling this.createGroup() inside the result handler; not outside of it. 
       // I'm also passing in the response.
       this.createGroup()
      }
      )
  }
```

Now, you your create group function should have access to this.exercises.

In your original implementation, `this.createGroup()` was most likely called before the result handler was run; and as such this.exercises would have been undefined.  But, it is hard to tell since no where in your original code is `this.exercises` defined or given a value.